# Elasticsearch: How to use aggregations with query?

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I'm a fresh bee in elastic search and I'm trying to query documents from elastic search with aggregation. The query looks like this:

`{
    "size": 25000,
    "query": {
      "filtered": {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": {
              "term": {
                "vlanId": [
                  2,
                  4,
                  8,
                  12,
                  16,
                  28,
                  0,
                  20,
                  24,
                  44,
                  544
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
            "must": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "ipv4"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "vlan_ids": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "vlanId"
        },
        "aggregations": {
          "top": {
            "top_hits": {
              "from": 0,
              "size": 10,
              "explain": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`

After the execution, I'm getting `Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed` exception. I'm using Java API and elasticsearch 1.4v. Any lead is much appreciated.

Here is the sample JSON:

```
{ "_index":"vlan-active",  "_source":{  "vlanId":8,  "port":3,  "vlanIP":"10.16.8.102",  "ipv4":"10.16.8.102",  "ipv6":"",  "mac":"",  "vendorName":"","os":""}}
```

Comment: Can you include your index configuration? Sample data?

Comment: Wasn't there any cause for the exception?

Comment: @TIM: Added the sample JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`term` query will match field to a single value.
In order to match multiple values like `in clause`, `terms` should be used instead of `term`.

I changed the keyword `term` to `terms` and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Your query starts and end with square brackets ("[]"), that is why it is not working. DSL queries should start with curly braces (i.e. "{}")

**Edit**: Removed the confusion due to my rhetorical question

Comment: It was a rhetorical question as given his query it's not possible to run. Fair point though, since it is confusing I'll edit it

Comment: Edited my post to clarify that it is an answer

Comment: @clearlight: Fair enough, I started being active recently, I'm not 100% on the rules. Thanks for your clarification!

Comment: toString() method added the sqaure brackets! Sorry, my bad! With cutly braces also, the query is not working.